# Simulate key events for text inputs?

Tags: java, events, gwt

How can I simulate a key press event for a text input.

I have a `GWT.TextArea` and on a certain condition I want to perform simulate a `KeyEvent` inside the textbox.
For testing, I tried to simulate the LEFT arrow key like this:

```
Sysout("SIMULATE");
Event event = Document.get().createKeyDownEvent(false, false, false, false, KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT).cast();
textArea.onBrowserEvent(event);
textArea.getElement().dispatchEvent(event);
```

I'm getting the sysout, but not the simulated key event. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "not the simulated key"? Also, try synthesizing all of `keydown`, `keyup` and `keypress`.

Comment: I mean the cursor gets not moved to the left as I would expect then simulating a hit on the left arrow key. I also tried all 3 event types without success.

Comment: I attached a custom key handler, and I can see that if I use `DomEvent.fireNativeEvent` at least the key event arrives at the handler. Anyhow the key event is not reflected inside the textarea box. The cursor is not moved by the event.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that using events in browsers. Try a combination of `getCursorPos` and `setCursorPos` maybe.